# tooltip shows out of td element for anchor tag in IE and chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got a requirement to show click percentage for each link available in HTML
template which is got from DB dynamically.

I had tried to display click percentage for each anchor link adding them to data-title using jQuery but the issue is when I hover the link tooltip was displaying at out range.

Can someone helpme out to show tooltip only when I hover nearthe anchor
link? or please give me a better solution..

I have attached all sample code in below fiddler link Please find the sample fiddle and code.

And In IE it is got like some where and in chrome it is diplaying some where

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ywncLh3/5/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var anchors = [];
     $(this).find("a").each(function () {
         anchors.push($(this));
     });

     for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
         var _ele = '100%'
         $(anchors[i]).attr('data-title', _ele);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a

```
display:inline-block;
```

to your links
and postition the labels accordingly

http://jsfiddle.net/6ywncLh3/9/